# How to get the browser to ask to save password and auto-fill login credentials

Tags: html, authentication, dotnetnuke, credential-manager

How can I modify my custom DNN login module so that the Browser can ask to save the password and also add the information to Web Credentials?

How the module currently works is that it has a Username field with a next button. As soon as you enter the correct username it would proceed to the next step to ask you for your password.

When you navigate to the login page, the username should already be filled in.

Thanks

Comment: The browser asks for saving `form` data if you create a form with for e.g. an `input` for username and an input for password.

Comment: @maurice Do I need to add a form tag as this is asp:inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This is in the browser settings, and depending on what the user wants, and for security reasons you can't change this programmatically.

In DNN, you have the option to check the "remember me" checkbox on the login form, this is setting a cookie which is valid for a defined time (this is done in the web.config file, search for persistantCookieTimeout and change the value. The value is in minutes as far as I remember, so to have it for 100 days ist is 60 x 24 x 100 = 144000. Default is 0, which means the cookie the login gets invalid at the end of the session.

For further information follow these links:

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/persistentcookietimeout

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134982/why-doesnt-remember-me-work-like-i-expect

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/appsettings-in-webconfig

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/disabling-support-for-persistent-cookies